# How can avoid web api method calling multiple using factory method in angular

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a drop down box filled with master data. This data I am using in Add and Edit functionality also means two controllers.  For getting and filling data into drop Down I used angular js and web api.  Implemented one factory service for calling web api and used the same factory service in these two controllers for calling factory. By doing like this the web Api calling two times in add and edit controller also. I think no need to call web Api method twice because that is a master data and getting that data only one time and using the same whenever we required.  Please help me how can avoid web Api calling two times.

Sample Code:

```
**Factory:**

        'use strict';
        app.factory('masterdataservice', ['$http', 'config', function ($http, config) {

            var masterdataserviceFactory = {};

            var urlBase = config.webApiUrl;

            masterdataserviceFactory.wwstatus = function () {
                return $http.get(urlBase + 'api/sca/wwstatus');
            };

            masterdataserviceFactory.wwseverity = function () {
                return $http.get(urlBase + 'api/sca/wwseverity');
            };

            return masterdataserviceFactory;
        }]);

**Controller:**

        app.controller('AddSupportProductCtrl', ['$scope','$http', 'masterdataservice',
        function ($scope, $http, masterdataservice) {

         masterdataservice.wwstatus()
                          .then(function (response) {
                              $scope.statues = response.data;
                          });

            masterdataservice.wwseverity()
                                     .then(function (response) {
                                         $scope.severites = response.data;
                                     });

        }]);
```

Comment: Please show the code that you are using.

Comment: two ways to save an extra api call. 1. assign the response data to a scope variable and always check scope variable before trying to call the service; 2. cache the response data in service

Comment: Right now I am not in a position to share the code to you.  I will share after some time.

Comment: we can use scope variables in a particular controller only but in my case add and edit functionality in two different controllers.

Comment: Attached sample code

Comment: Anyone have any idea?